# Read data from url in javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

i'm trying to read data stored in google drive, on drive or other cloud storage using javascript
`

```
let btn = document.getElementById('action-btn');



btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // let baseurl = document.getElementById('inputurl').value;
    // let guidDcoument = baseurl.split('#guid=')[1];
    // const query = encodeURIComponent('Select *')
    // fetch('', {
    //     mode: "no-cors",
    //     method: "get",
    // }).then(Response => console.log(Response))
    fetch('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kwfv6L2lBrPw8OjHGyhO7YHOXFNwHYyPI_noM5TUMLw/edit?pli=1#gid=1097732605',{
        mode:"no-cors"
    })
    .then((response) => { console.log(Response.error); })
    .catch(console.error())
})
```

`
What I need is that given a url, I can read the data from the file, and then show them on my website.

I think that when I try to access any other cloud storage I will have the same problem. That it will be necessary to access the account to be able to read the data that would be a csv document.

Comment: What is `Response.error` and why do you use it in the handler?

Comment: Yes, you will need to authenticate yourself before accessing a Google Drive file, and you can't get the file content using `fetch`. You will need to use the dedicated API for that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you're trying to achieve is called 'web scraping' and you can't use `fetch` for that, instead you should use `puppeteer` (in the server side), which is the most popular library for `web scraping`.

Run `npm init -y` to initialize a npm project and install puppeteer `npm i puppeteer` and also install express and cors `npm i express cors` in order to create a server that scraps data and sets it back to your client. So, instead of trying to scrap the information directly from the client you do it from the server with puppeteer.

Try the following `.js` server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  app.use('/', async (req, res) => {
    await page.goto('url-to-the-website')
    const data = {}
    return res.json(data)
  })
})()

app.listen(3000)
```

And learn more about puppeteer: https://pptr.dev/.

And your client code should connect to this server to send scrape requests to it like this:

```
(async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000')
  const rawjson = await res.json()
  const json = JSON.parse(rawjson)
  console.log(json)
})
```

Note: we wrap the code in anonymous functions with the reserved word `async` in order to use `async` and `await` syntax. More information: https://javascript.info/async-await.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer your question, your explanation has helped me a lot, I will try it.